# ¿Cómo crear un gráfico en R que totalice observaciones frente a una variable categórica?

Tags: r, gráficas

Tengo una data.frame con la siguiente estructura

```
semana  ej_obs
1       2
1       1
1       0
2       0
2       3
2       4
2       4
2       1
3       2
3       0
3       1
3       1
```

Necesito generar un gráfico que represente la suma de observaciones cada semana. En este caso, algo como

[image: gráfico]

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola espero que esto responda tu pregunta, esto lo realice usando la librería de ggplot2 y stat_summary que tienen el argumento fun.y que ayuda a aplicar a un vector numérico una función de  agregado

```
install.packages(ggplot2)
library(ggplot2)
df<-data.frame(semana=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),ej_obs=c(2,1,0,0,3,4,4,1,2,0,1,1))
ggplot(df ,aes(x = semana, y = ej_obs))  +  
stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="bar")
```

[image: Este es el resultado del código anterior]

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer con R base de la siguiente manera:

Primero a tus columnas los creo en un data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(semana=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),ej_obs=c(2,1,0,0,3,4,4,1,2,0,1,1))
```

Luego aplicas los siguiente:

```
ed<-aggregate(ej_obs~semana, data = df, sum)
```

Con esto se genera la suma de los `ej_obs` por `semana`. Luego haces la gráfica con un `barplot`.

```
barplot(ed$ej_obs~ed$semana, xlab = "Semanas", ylab = "Suma de ej_obs", col=c("cadetblue3","cornflowerblue","gold1"),
        main="La gráfica")
```

Le agregué algunos detallitos, pero con `barplot(ed$ej_obs~ed$semana)` es suficiente.

Es así como te resultaría.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]